# Pivoting on two columns and adding to existing database

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Suppose I have the following contrived example:

```
    ids        types    values                                                                                                                                
     1          a         10                                                                                                                           
     1          b         11                                                                                                                             
     1          c         12
     2          a         -10
     2          b         -11 
     3          a         100
```

Is there way to use panda.pivot() to get the following table?

```
    ids      a     b     c                                                                                                                                 
     1       10    11    12   
     2      -10   -11    NaN 
     3       100   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: duplicates of [how to pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe): `df.pivot('ids','types', 'values')`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this -

```
df.pivot(index='ids', columns='types', values='values')
types      a     b     c
ids
1       10.0  11.0  12.0
2      -10.0 -11.0   NaN
3      100.0   NaN   NaN
```